# Vertical LinearLayout within vertical LinearLayout ignores layout:weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a grid of buttons with accompanying titles. When I create one button with its title, there are no problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.havenseedsforsuccess.havenseedsforsuccess.PlantList"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientfill">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="What&apos;s Growing?"
        android:id="@+id/textPlantListTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBrown"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="9.25"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPlantListTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="12"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:src="@drawable/plantfiller"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="3.5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Plant Name"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBrown"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5" />

             </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code above gives me the layout I'm looking for:

[image]

But, when I copy-paste the button/title's vertical LinearLayout to create a second one below it, everything gets all wonky and stretched out of shape. The layout:weight isn't being followed anymore, and each button/title LinearLayout takes up about half the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.havenseedsforsuccess.havenseedsforsuccess.PlantList"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientfill">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="What&apos;s Growing?"
        android:id="@+id/textPlantListTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBrown"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="9.25"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPlantListTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="12"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:src="@drawable/plantfiller"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="3.5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Plant Name"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBrown"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:src="@drawable/plantfiller"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_weight="3.5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Plant Name"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBrown"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5" />


             </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above code gives me this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a picture with what is really going on? I asking that because I don't know why you need so many vertical layouts.

Comment: I added pictures. I guess my reputation is too low to add any actual images, so they're in link form.

Comment: Why do you have 3 LinearLayouts inside each other?

Comment: I updated my code so I only have 2 linear layouts, one organizing the two columns of buttons / titles so they take up 50% of the screen's width, and then on organizing the buttons and their respective titles vertically. However, I still have the same problem as before. I'm very new to Android Studio, so I'm still feeling my way around formatting activities and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `<ScrollView>`. You are trying to resize the buttons with the `<weight>` tag, but `<ScrollView>` makes your screen infinite, so android just don't resize.

Just remove the `<ScrollView>` and I think that you will achieve what you want.

If somehow need the `<ScrollView>` you want a lot of buttons, in a Google Play style, do some research and check screen sizes and just make `<weight>` a fixed value for each screen size, since you don't have to worry if all the buttons show up on the screen.

Comment: So instead of using weights, I should use set heights for each screen size?

Comment: It depends if you want to use ScrollView and still fill the screen exactly with, for example, 4 buttons. If you to make a lot of buttons like your first button,just remove the scrollView.

Comment: The idea was that I'd have two columns of buttons that extended past the bottom of the screen, and the user could then scroll down to see more.  I'm not sure exactly how many buttons I'll need, but I'm worried that trying to fit too many buttons in a single frame of the screen would make the screen seem cluttered and hard to use.